# How do I add 2 signature fields for the same signer to the same document?

Tags: docusignapi

Via the DocuSign API, how do I add 2 signature fields to a document, that must be signed by the same signer?  Ex. the document has 2 different sections, which both need a signature from the same individual.

When I try to add multiple signers with the same email address via the API I get the following error:

```
{
  "errorCode": "ENVELOPE_HAS_DUPLICATE_RECIPIENTS",
  "message": "The specified envelope has duplicate recipients."
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add another signature node in your JSON for the same recipient.  Like this:

```
"tabs": {
    "signHereTabs": [
        {
            "xPosition": "100",
            "yPosition": "100",
            "documentId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1"
        },
        {
            "xPosition": "200",
            "yPosition": "200",
            "documentId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1"
        }       
    ]
}
```

This would place 2 signature tabs on page 1 of document 1 of the envelope.  The first signature location is at (100,100) and the second will be placed at (200,200).